# Factory class with database connection in spring

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I need to write a factory class with calls to the database and stores the data into a static object. I know how to write this as a normal java. But am not able to do in spring. Am able to get the pattern, but not getting the database connection when "factory-method" is called. Below is code

```
public class ApplicationSettingsDAO {

private static ApplicationSettingsDAO objSettings = null; // new ApplicationSettingsDAO();

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

private ApplicationSettingsDAO() {
    getDBConncection();
}


public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return this.dataSource;
}

public static ApplicationSettingsDAO getInstance() {
    if (objSettings == null) {
        synchronized (ApplicationSettingsDAO.class) {
            if (objSettings == null) {
                objSettings = new ApplicationSettingsDAO();
            }
        }
    }
    return objSettings;
}

public void getDBConncection() {
    System.out.println("dataSource -> " + dataSource);
    try {
        Connection objConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement objPrepStatement = objConnection.prepareStatement("Select ApplicationSettingID, SettingID, Value From ApplicationSetting");
        ResultSet objResultSet =  objPrepStatement.executeQuery();
        while(objResultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println("--> " + objResultSet.getInt("SettingID") + " >> " + objResultSet.getString("Value"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Bean configuration

```
<bean id="objSettings" class="com.schoolcity.stars.dao.common.ApplicationSettingsDAO" factory-method="getInstance" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Am not able get the dataSource object on container startup. But it works if I call

```
 ApplicationSettingsDAO.getInstance().getDBConncection();
```

I need to invoke getDBConncection() when getInstance() is called.

Thank You

Comment: And why do you need this contraption? Why couldn't you do this with a normal Spring bean?

Comment: I need to have singleton class for some of the settings present in one table. As there is a difference b/w spring singleton and Singleton pattern.

Comment: Well yes and in general the singleton pattern must be seen as an anti-pattern. Why wouldn't it work as a normal spring bean?

Comment: It is working now. I just put getDBConncection() method in setDataSource().